# Tensorflow could not correctly convert string (float) to Int

Tags: python-3.x, string, tensorflow, floating-point

For example I have this `string` tensor:

```
s = tf.constant('154.0', dtype=tf.string)
```

I want to convert it to a `tf.int32` tensor:

```
tf.strings.to_number(s, out_type=tf.int32)
```

But I got the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: 154.0 [Op:StringToNumber]
```

Why is this happening? Is it because the string '154.0' contains a decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the string-number you are specifying is seen as a float, while you ask for a direct cast to int. You could try to:

- pass a string representing an int and see if it works (it should); or
- let tensorflow do an automatic cast without specifying the `out_type` and then cast the output tensor to int32, using, for instance, tf.cast https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast